# Why don't the jQuery Cycle images overlap each other?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I am putting a common garden variety cycle slideshow on this page: http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/index-new. For some reason the images don't overlap like they do here in my test configuration: http://www.orientalhealthsolutions.com/cycle.html

Here is the html:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <img src="/photos/slideshow-1.jpg" alt="slideshow-1" width="600" height="410" />
    <img src="/photos/slideshow-2.jpg" alt="slideshow-2" width="600" height="410" />
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$('.slideshow').cycle({
   fx: 'fade' 
});
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.slideshow  { 
    width: 600px; 
    height: 410px; 
    overflow: hidden;  
    }
```

I get an error message that $ is not a function, so I either have a conflict or I've messed something else up. Any mentoring-guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah looks as though you have a conflict going on with something.

In chrome: `console.log($)` is undefined, where as `console.log(jQuery)` works.

Quick fix change `$('.slideshow')` to `jQuery('.slideshow')`

Comment: This is just a quick fix though, so you would be best trying to find a more elegant solution to avoid this in the future.